# PHP - child processes doesn't exit properly

Tags: php, process, multiprocessing, fork, exit

I have the following PHP script. I need to do 5 different tasks with 5 differents child-processes (using pcntl_fork() function). Childs are created correctly and they do their stuff, but it seems like they never exit. Parent wait they to end but it never happens. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if ($pid == -1) {
        die("Error Creating subprocess ".$i);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (!$pid) {

        switch ($i) {
            case 1:
                // Child 1
                error_log("I\'m the child number ".$i." PID: ".getmypid()."\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
                //Doing some stuff
                exit;
            case 2:
                // Child 2
                error_log("I\'m the child number ".$i." PID: ".getmypid()."\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
                //Doing some stuff
                exit;
            case 3:
                // Child 3
                error_log("I\'m the child number ".$i." PID: ".getmypid()."\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
                //Doing some stuff
                exit;
            case 4:
                // Child 4
                error_log("I\'m the child number ".$i." PID: ".getmypid()."\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
                //Doing some stuff
                exit;
            case 5:
                // Child 5
               error_log("I\'m the child number ".$i." PID: ".getmypid()."\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
                //Doing some stuff
                exit;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        $pids[] = $pid;
    }
}

error_log("Luke, I\'m your father. PID: ".getmypid()."\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
foreach ($pids as $key => $child) {
    $res = pcntl_waitpid($child, $status);
    //Check if this child has exited normally
    if (pcntl_wifexited($status))
        error_log("Child ".$child." has ended\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
    else
        error_log("Child ".$child." is zombie\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");

    if($res == -1 || $res > 0)
        unset($pids[$key]);
}
?>
```

Comment: you should always have a default case in switch. (this is just a note)

Comment: Thanks! I just edited that on the post

Comment: Why do you `exit;` and `break;` ??

Comment: You're right, `break;` is unnecessary here, but I don't think this could be the problem. I've just edited that

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();

    if ($pid == -1) {
        die("Error Creating subprocess ".$i);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (!$pid) {

        switch ($i) {
            case 1:
                // Child 1
                error_log("I\'m the child number ".$i." PID: ".getmypid()."\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
                //Doing some stuff
                exit;
            case 2:
                // Child 2
                error_log("I\'m the child number ".$i." PID: ".getmypid()."\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
                //Doing some stuff
                exit;
            case 3:
                // Child 3
                error_log("I\'m the child number ".$i." PID: ".getmypid()."\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
                //Doing some stuff
                exit;
            case 4:
                // Child 4
                error_log("I\'m the child number ".$i." PID: ".getmypid()."\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
                //Doing some stuff
                exit;
            case 5:
                // Child 5
               error_log("I\'m the child number ".$i." PID: ".getmypid()."\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
                //Doing some stuff
                exit;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        $pids[$pid] = $pid;
    }
}

while (!empty($pids)) {
  if ($child = pcntl_wait($status, WNOHANG)) {
    if (pcntl_wifexited($status))
        error_log("Child ".$child." has ended\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
    else
        error_log("Child ".$child." is zombie\n", 3, "/var/log/php_errors.log");
    unset($pids[$child]);    
  } else
    usleep(100);
}
```

Dont forget to change $pids[] = $pid; to $pids[$pid] = $pid; :o) or choose better way to pop from array exited child.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I made these changes but it still doesn't works :(. This is what I get on my php_errors.log file:  
`Luke, I'm your father. PID: 8986  `
`Luke, I'm your father. PID: 8986  `
`I'm the child number 1 PID: 9980  `
`Luke, I'm your father. PID: 8986  `
`I'm the child number 2 PID: 9981  `
`Luke, I'm your father. PID: 8986  `
`I'm the child number 3 PID: 9982  `
`Luke, I'm your father. PID: 8986  `
`I'm the child number 4 PID: 9983  `
`Luke, I'm your father. PID: 8986  `
`I'm the child number 5 PID: 9984`

Comment: Try to use exit(0); instead of exit;

Comment: I've already tried that. But the result is the same, I tried `exit;`, `exit()`, `exit($i)` and exit(0).